# Get Wordpress user Information

Tags: wordpress, rest

I'm building a mobile application that will be an offline version of a wordpress site.

I need to verify users have an account on this wordpress site and have a certain paid membership to access the site.

I've been poking around different things for a couple days now and haven't found a good solution for this. I tried the wp-rest-api but they don't have any endpoints exposed that have the data I need.

I'm also not super familiar with wordpress to know how things interact and work.

Is there a rest endpoint I can use? or a way I can create a rest endpoint, and if so how do i interact with the user database on wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended solving the problem through a couple round about ways.

First I piggybacked off of the currently in place login requests.  I just monitored the network requested using chrome inspect and found a "/login-APPNAME.php" request and copied the parameters and made the same request in my app.

It's a little hacky because I have to parse the html response for keywords to determine if they successfully logged in, but it works to verify a user.

Then once the user is verified I was able to get more information about them that I needed from the Woocomerce api.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the [Basic Authentication plugin](https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth) on the WordPress site
2. Use the Curl or WP_http menthod for the authentication. Both methods are listed in the github page.

Comment: Still doesn't accomplish the task. None of the wp rest endpoints return all the user information, in this case what their membership level is.

Comment: Also tried it anyways, pursuing using basic auth and another workaround but that plugin isn't supported anymore in current wp or wp-rest version

Answer (score 0):

global $current_user;

$user = get_currentuserinfo();

print_r($user);

It will give you all user information